# Regular expression that uses an "OR" conditional

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I could use some help writing a regular expression.  In my Django application, users can hit the following URL:

```
http://www.example.com/A1/B2/C3
```

I'd like to create a regular expression that allows accepts any of the following as a valid URL:

```
http://www.example.com/A1  
http://www.example.com/A1/B2  
http://www.example.com/A1/B2/C3
```

I'm guessing I need to use the "OR" conditional, but I'm having trouble getting my regex to validate.  Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**: Here is the regex so far.  Note that I have not included the "http://www.example.com" portion -- Django handles that for me.  I'm just concerned with validating 1,2, or 3 subdirectories.

```
^(\w{1,20})|((\w{1,20})/(\w{1,20}))|((\w{1,20})/(\w{1,20})/(\w{1,20}))$
```

Comment: Just to clarify:  You want it to accept the three examples but reject anything else?  I.E. http://www.somewebsite.com/A1/B1 would be unacceptable?

Comment: http://www.somewebsite.com/A1/B1 would be fine.  I'm just looking for something that will validate three different sub-directories.

Comment: Can you post the regex you have so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Skip the `|`, use the `?` and `()`

`http://www\.example\.com/A1(/B2(/C3)?)?`

And if you replace the A1-C3 with a pattern:

`http://www\.example\.com/[^/]*(/[^/]*(/[^/]*)?)?`

Explanation:

- it matches every string that starts with `http://www.example.com/A1`
- it can match an additional `/B2` and even an additional `/C3`, but `/C3` is only matched, when there is a `/B2`
- `[^/]*` (as many non slashes as possible)
- if you need the A1-C3 in special capture groups, you can use this:

`http://www\.example\.com/([^/]*)(/([^/]*)(/([^/]*))?)?`

Will give (`groupnumber: content`):

```
matches: 0: (http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3)
1: (dir1)
2: (/dir2/dir3)
3: (dir2)
4: (/dir3)
5: (dir3)
```

You can check it out online [here](http://www.regextester.com/) or get this [tool](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/) (yes it's free, and it's even written in Lisp...).

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you wanted to test whether a URL ends with .html or .pdf, but didn't care about what it began with, what would the regex expression look like?

Answer (score 3):

There's a much more Django way to do this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<object_slug1>\w{2}/(?P<object_slug2>\w{2}/(?P<object_slug3>\w{2})$', direct_to_template, {"template": "two_levels_deep.html"}, name="two_deep"),
    url(r'^(?P<object_slug1>\w{2}/(?P<object_slug2>\w{2})$', direct_to_template, {"template": "one_level_deep.html"}, name="one_deep"),
    url(r'^(?P<object_slug1>\w{2})$', direct_to_template, {"template": "homepage.html"}, name="home"),
)
```

The other methods don't take advantage of Django's power to pass variables.

Edit: I switched the order of the urlpattern to be more obvious for the parser (i.e. bottom up is more defined than top down).

Answer (score 1):

```
http://www\.example\.com/A1(/B2(/C3)?)?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 ^(\w{1,20})(/\w{1,20})*
```

this is for as many subdirectories as you like if you only want 2:

```
 ^(\w{1,20})(/\w{1,20}){0,2}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding, I think you just need another set of parens around the whole OR statement:

```
^((\w{1,20})|((\w{1,20})/(\w{1,20}))|((\w{1,20})/(\w{1,20})/(\w{1,20})))$
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that Django's [reverse URL matching](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#id2) (permalinks, `reverse()` and `{% url %}`) can handle a limited subset of regular expressions. To be able to use them, it's sometimes necessary to split complex regexes into separate URL dispatcher rules.